# Waiting for a dynamic iFrame to load using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Let's say I'm creating a dynamic iFrame like this:

```
$('body').prepend('<iframe id="e" src="/page.html"></iframe>');
```

Now I want to wait for this iFrame to finish loading so that I can access its source.
I could do this using:

```
$('#e').load(function() {}
```

However, if there is an image or anything on "/page.html" that takes a long time to load, then I'm simply waiting for nothing, because all I need is the source.

So my question is, is it possible to do something like this instead:

```
while not exists ($("#e").contents().find('#someid')) { //wait }
```

So this simply waits until '#someid' exists in our iFrame (meaning at least the source code finished loaded).

Is this possible?

Comment: try to see if `$('#e').ready(function() {}` helps.

Comment: Hello thank you but it won't work with a dynamic iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

In main window you can declare function (lets say `iframeReady`):

```
function iframeReady() {
    //your code
}
```

And put the following code to the end of `body` tag inside iframe:

```
<script>
parent.window.iframeReady();
</script>
```

So you can access the parent window via `parent` object

Thus `parent.window.iframeReady` will be called exactly when `body` content is loaded and will not wait till all images are loaded

**Caveat**: it will only work if parent window and iframe have the same domain

Comment: Hello thank you, but I cannot edit the iFrame page in advance since the content varies.

Comment: @P.Henderson if you add `parent.window.iframeReady();` to the very end of `body` tag it will execute when all content is probably loaded. To ensure this, you may call `iframeReady` in `setTimeout` (in 10ms). Or you can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) inside an iframe, but it will not work in IE8 and older